# Logic recording quality with Apogee Jam+

Tags: audio, music, logic

When I am not recording my guitar sounds great through Logic Pro. If I had to quantify it, I would say it was CD quality or higher.

However, when I make a recording with my Apogee Jam Plus it sounds like a cassette that has been played too many sounds. The recording is not high fidelity at all.

Some things I have tinkered with:

- Enabled 24 bit
- Increased my Apogee Jam to 96K in the MIDI settings.

I believe the sample rate is set to 44.1 MHz which is CD quality.

I just enabled Expert Mode which opened up additional settings but still couldn’t find anything.

Comment: What interface are you using to connect your guitar to Logic Pro?

Comment: I’m using the Apogee Jam+. It sounds crystal clear with input monitoring. Just recording is a problem.

Comment: I don't know the Apogee or Logic specifically enough to tell you precisely where to look, but some things to check. When just listening, are you certain you're actually going through the computer? Do you hear some latency? The Apogee has a direct routing switch, so you may be listening just to its direct out, not via the Mac. Once in the Mac, are you checking your gain-staging is correct on Logic's input/output meters? If you're over there you will affect the entire recording. If you can post a snippet to somewhere publically accessible, soundcloud etc, maybe hearing it would give more clues.

Comment: The sound was going through the Mac though I'm not sure what gain staging is. The (gain?) meter had been in the green most of the time. Anyways I think I was able to fix it though I'm not sure what I did. I did increase the sample rate to 96k. The Apogee MIDI setting was also set to 96k. I may have toggled some other settings too though I'm not sure what they are now. Thanks anyways for suggestions!